# Get ErrorWidget size for rebuild

Tags: flutter

To get the size/position of a widget on screen, I can use GlobalKey to get its BuildContext and then find the RenderBox.

But for ErrorWidget(Red Screen) when build() error happened I want to calculate the error area's size, and then decide whether to destroy the page or replace with other widget e.g. Container().

I have already used ErrorWidget.builder create custom ErrorWidget, but need to be more precise, different sizes of ErrorWidget are treated differently. How to get ErrorWidget size for rebuild?

Answer (score 0):

`ErrorWidget` do not evade the widgets rules.
A widget cannot depend on the size of anything else.

You can, however, use `LayoutBuilder` to calculate the available size.

Comment: This is a good idea, use LayoutBuilder check constraints logic.

Answer (score 0):

`LayoutBuilder` Widget can help us know how much space is available for the child widget, before finally build it. It's builder function has parameters `BuildContext` context, `BoxConstraints` constraints.

`BoxConstraints` constraints provides us with the opportunity to execute custom logic.

```
ErrorWidget.builder = (FlutterErrorDetails details) {
  return LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
      Size screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
      double screenRatio = (constraints.maxWidth * constraints.maxHeight) /
          (screenSize.width * screenSize.height);

      if (screenRatio < ACCEPTABLE_SCREEN_RATIO) {
        return Container();
      } 

      return ErrorWidget(details.exception);
    },
  );
};
```